# Should I call shutdown() on fds before exit from server?

Tags: c, select, server, shutdown, file-descriptor

When the server receives a termination signal it exits from the loop where the select() is monitoring the fds in the set (fd_set).

It is necessary look through fds and call shutdown(fd, SHUT_RDWR) if there are any of them still in the set? Or should I call close(fd)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not necessary to call `shutdown()` before `close()`. When you close a socket, it's automatically shut down in both directions.

You generally only need to use `shutdown()` if you need to keep the socket open for some reason. This might be done in a protocol where the end of the request is indicated by EOF; you call `shutdown(fd, SHUT_WR)` to send EOF, then read the response.

Comment: So I should do something like this?
for (fd=0;fd<fdmax;fd++){
     if (FD_ISSET(fd, mrset))
          close(fd);
}

Comment: Not sure what `FD_ISSET` has to do with it. If the server is exiting it should close all FDs, not just the ones in `mrset`. But this happens automatically when a process terminates.

Comment: FD_ISSET tests if the correspondent fd is in the set and so if there is still a connection engaged with some client that need to be closed.
Maybe I'm just complicating the situation.

Comment: You should be closing each connection after you're done with it, so when the server ends there shouldn't be any open connections, except the listening one. If it's ending unexpectedly, it can just exit and depend on the automatic closes.